# Making a Modern FPS game health regeneration system in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to make a regeneration after time system but whatever i did it didn't work,
basically it is something like this:

Player gets hit, waits 2-3 seconds and regeneration starts. But i couldn't make the "waits 2-3 seconds" to regenerate.

Code:

```
    private void Hit()
{        
    if (PlayerShield > 0)
    {
        PlayerShield -= EnemyScript.EnemyBulletDamage;
    }
    else
    {
        Health = Health - EnemyScript.EnemyBulletDamage;
    }
    Invoke("Regen", 3);
    
    if (Health < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("player dead");
    }
}
private void Regen()
{
    while (PlayerShield < 120)
    {
        PlayerShield += 10*Time.deltaTime;
        if (PlayerShield > 120)
        {
            PlayerShield = 120;
        }
    }

}
```

when i run this if player doesn't get hit a couple times this code works but if it gets multiple hits in 3 seconds it doesn't restart the waiting process and this is my main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution here is to use [`CancelInvoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html) before each `Invoke` call:

```
private void Hit()
{        
    if (PlayerShield > 0)
    {
        PlayerShield -= EnemyScript.EnemyBulletDamage;
    }
    else
    {
        Health = Health - EnemyScript.EnemyBulletDamage;
    }
    CancelInvoke("Regen");
    Invoke("Regen", 3);
    
    if (Health < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("player dead");
    }
}
private void Regen()
{
    while (PlayerShield < 120)
    {
        PlayerShield += 10*Time.deltaTime;
        if (PlayerShield > 120)
        {
            PlayerShield = 120;
        }
    }

}
```